# Text entry not available in the tray icon ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

I have updated from ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 and the text entry becomes unavailable, it does not show up in the tray anymore even I ticked in option 'Show current input source in the menu bar'.
Here is the screenshot.

[text entry](http://tinypic.com/r/fvlpxe/8)

Please help me. Thanks.